# Ambiguous Column Name Even Though Column Name and Table are Declared?

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

I am trying to create a query based on trying to find a value in one column of a table based on the values of another column in another table. This is the code I have written so far,

```
SELECT OrderDetails.OrderDetailID FROM OrderDetails
INNER JOIN OrderDetails
ON Products.ProductID = OrderDetails.ProductID
WHERE Products.SupplierID="5";
```

By executing the code, I want to find the OrderDetailID of the row in the OrderID Table where the SupplierID in the Products table is 5. For example,

[Highlighted Products Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZU3o.png)

The SupplierID of "Queso Cabrales" is 5 and its ProductID is 11. This corresponds to the foreign key in the table OrderDetail of 11 and therefore I want the primary key of that row to be returned. In this case 1.

[Highlighted OrderDetails Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0Oky.png)

At the moment I get an "ambiguous column name" error in the first line even though I have declared both the table and the column name. Also, how am I meant to ask SQL to fetch the data regarding other tables. I know I am mean't to use "INNER JOIN" but how do I execute so the WHERE command can be used.

Comment: You are `JOIN`ing `OrderDetails` to `OrderDetails` on `Products.ProductId`.  Perhaps you meant to do a `JOIN` on `OrderDetails` and `Products` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `OrderDetails` twice in the `FROM` clause but no `Products`.  I think you mean:

```
SELECT od.OrderDetailID
FROM OrderDetails od INNER JOIN
     Products p
     ON p.ProductID = od.ProductID
WHERE p.SupplierID = 5;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and read (the `od` and `p`).
- Don't use delimiters around numeric constants.  I assume that `SupplierId` is a number, so I removed the double quotes.

Comment: Especially like the added comment about removing quotes if unnecessary.  Way to address the whole problem, not just the base question.

Answer (score 0):

You are using two time the same column so you must resove the amvbiguity eg: this way (using two distinct alias  od1, od2)

```
    SELECT od1.OrderDetailID FROM OrderDetails od1
    INNER JOIN OrderDetails as od2
    ON Products.ProductID = od2.ProductID
    WHERE Products.SupplierID="5";
```

Comment: but then `products.productID` would fail :P as would `products.supplierID`  I think they meant to use products once.

Comment: I'm not in the logic of the query ..but the  ambiguity is related  to the fact that the OP are using two time the same table  ..without proper  alias ..

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that `INNER JOIN` was designed to generate duplicate columns in the result. This problem was solved in 1992 when the SQL standard introduced 'relational' join types that don't generate duplicate attributes:

```
SELECT OrderDetailID
  FROM OrderDetails 
       NATURAL JOIN Products
 WHERE SupplierID = 5;
```